# Remove /duplicate tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions with the tag [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) cover duplicate files, duplicate packages, duplicate lines and many more. Even if restricted to a specific usage, I can't think of any advantage of this tag, so I recommend to delete it.

Comment: I agree. The tag has 0 followers so I doubt any one else thinks it's useful.

Comment: yes, we don't need duplicates

Comment: yes, we don't need duplicates

Comment: Nice that everyone agreed, but now we need someone allowed to actually do it ...

Answer (score 1):

This tag is ambiguous, but not useless. It conveys information which is relevant in searches. **Please do not remove it without replacing it with a more precise tag.**

Most uses seem to be about:

- Looking for identical or similar files → I just created [duplicate-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files)
- Looking for duplicate lines or fields in a file (this should usually be used together with [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing), but often isn't)

What else?